# HTTP/2 nginx force redirect HTTP to HTTPS breaks expected behaviour

Tags: redirect, curl, nginx, docker

I've setup an example project that uses the latest version of nginx which supports HTTP/2.

I was going off this official blog post: https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-9-5/

Here is a working code example (with details of how to setup everything within the README - `nginx.conf` pasted below as well): https://github.com/Integralist/Docker-Examples/tree/master/Nginx-HTTP2

```
user nobody nogroup;
worker_processes auto;

events {
  worker_connections 512;
}

http {
  upstream app {
    server app:4567;
  }

  server {
    listen *:80 http2;

    location /app/ {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen *:443 ssl http2;
    server_name integralist.com;

    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/ca.crt;

    location /app/ {
      proxy_pass http://app/;
    }
  }
}
```

Although the example works, I've hit an issue where by if I go to the service endpoint within my browser using HTTP,  it'll first download a file called `download` and *then* redirect correctly to HTTPS.

I'm not sure what this file is or why the redirection causes it to happen, but its content is `Äˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ` ?

If I try using `curl` (e.g. curl --insecure http://$dev_ip:$dev_80/app/foo) the redirect fails to happen and I think it's because of this weird downloaded file? The response from curl to stdout is just `??????`

I wonder if this is possibly a side-effect of using Docker to containerize the Ruby application and the nginx server?

### Update

I removed `http2` from `listen *:80 http2;` so it now reads `listen *:80;` and the download doesn't happen but the problem I have is trying to get the redirect to point to the correct docker port now :-/

To clarify, I have an nginx container with dynamic port generation (`-P`). One port for accessing the containerized nginx service on `:80` and one for `:443` - my nginx.conf is redirecting traffic from HTTP to HTTPS but I need to be able to identify the 443 port number.

e.g. `docker ps` shows `0.0.0.0:32791->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32790->443/tcp`

I'm trying to redirect http://example.com:32791/app/foo to https://example.com:32790/app/foo

I'm not sure how I could configure nginx to know the relevant 443 Docker port number as that's dynamically generated?

I could be explicit and use `-p` when running the nginx container. But I'd still need to pass that port number into nginx as a variable somehow (a quick google would suggest using Docker's `-e "my_port=9999"` and then access it using nginx's `env` declaration)

### Update 2

I've even tried swapping to explicit ports `-p` and then hardcoding the port number into the `nginx.conf` with no luck (e.g. `docker run ... -p 60443:443 -p 60080:80`)...

```
listen *:80;

location /app/ {
  return 301 https://$host:60443$request_uri;
}
```

...if I hit http://example.com:60080/app/ it gets redirected to https://example.com:60443/ so almost there but the actual path `/app/` wasn't added to the end when redirecting?

Answer (score 0):

> the problem I have is trying to get the redirect to point to the correct docker port now

If your nginx docker container is linked ([`docker run --link`](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#communication-across-links)) with the ruby one, the correct port is the one **[`EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#expose)**(d) in the ruby container image (even if you don't know to which host port that EXPOSE port was mapped)

A direct link container-to-container can use the port mentioned in the dockerfile.

Comment: I think I wasn't very clear in my description (apologies - I've reworded). Effectively I'm running the nginx container and linking the ruby container into that. But what I need to know is the nginx's dynamic port number assigned to 80/443 which is EXPOSE'd

Comment: I'm not using that no. That seems to be a bit overkill for my requirements.

Comment: Looking at GitHub it seems that the problem of a container being able to query itself is still outstanding. Lots of complicated hacks I've since seen around how to get things like the containers dynamically exposed ports

Comment: @Integralist would docker inspect able to show you those ports?

Comment: I assume that wouldn't work from inside the running nginx container though

Comment: BTW, I've added an "Update 2"

Comment: @Integralist why would you need to know an host port from within docker container though? The all idea of the internal container port is not having to worry about runtime ports (the one you map at `docker run` time)

Comment: @Integralist In other words, from one container (like the nginx one) you are not supposed to redirect to a host port, only to other containers ports. That what I do when I redirect to apache containers in my project: https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/1a3a147bb59a209f1cedd0c37c4a2cddef3d6ea5/nginx/env.conf#L51-L56

Comment: @Integralist an nginx container does not redirect to a server, only to localhost:<exposed port of another container on the same server>: a container does not have to worry about how another container managed by the same docker daemon is run.

Comment: To be honest I feel like I've lost the thread here a bit :-) in summary I have HTTPS working fine and would like to find the simplest way of redirecting any HTTP traffic to HTTPS. According to the nginx blog something like https://github.com/Integralist/Docker-Examples/blob/master/Nginx-HTTP2/docker-nginx/nginx.conf#L13-L19 is supposed do the job, but that doesn't appear to be the case when using containers

Comment: @Integralist The thing is, when you are in a container, you don't redirect to the host anymore, or to a dynamic port on the host. You are in docker world, redirecting to docker containers managed by the docker daemon. And one of the strong suits of that world is that you are supposed to know all about it in advanced (as specified by the dockerfile)